# State of the art in controlled english languages?

Tags: english, computational-linguistics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_natural_language lists some controlled languages, of which Attempto Controlled English seems to be the most recent. However, are there any Attempto extensions, or completely separate approaches, which extend it even more?